# regex for extracting a suffix with an exception

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract a "name" from a list of css classes.  The name always follows "lms-menuitem-" but there is an exception, "selected"  is not a valid "name".

The following works, but is terribly verbose. So what I want to do is rewrite the following code with a simple regex to get me the "name"

```
var targetSection="lms-menuitem lms-menuitem-addUsers lms-menuitem-selected";

targetSection=targetSection.replace(" lms-menuitem-selected","");
targetSection=targetSection.replace("lms-menuitem ","");
targetSection=targetSection.match(/lms-menuitem-(.*)/)[1];

alert(targetSection=='addUsers');
```

so what I'm looking for is something like:

```
var targetSection="lms-menuitem lms-menuitem-addUsers lms-menuitem-selected";    
alert(targetSection.match(/YOUR HELP HERE/)[1]=='addUsers');
```

an explanation of your pattern would be nice too!

Comment: `/lms-menuitem-(?!selected\b)([a-z]+)\b/i`  , it's called ["negative lookahead"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thanks! Just to confirm, though [a-z] would not catch "addUsers"  right?  that would need to be [A-Za-z] ?  Also, did you not want to make an official answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: it will find `addUsers` too(Note the `i` at the end, it's the Case-insensitive-flag)